# What stops the middle point of a power line from falling?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

Say you have a system that is a uniformly weighted string with slack suspended from two points; i.e. a power line.

There are three forces acting on any given point on this string: string tension going left, string tension going right, and gravity.

Consider the point exactly in the middle of the string.  The tension forces act tangent to the string, which (in this case) is directly left and right.  So these forces have no upwards component, so no matter how large they are, they won't be able to counteract gravity.

But the string is not moving, and the middle point is not actually accelerating downwards.  So what am I missing?  What's counteracting gravity?

Comment: That the power line is a rigid body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part at the exact middle of the string has zero mass.

That seems silly, but consider - if you consider a very small section of the string in the middle - say 1 mm - then the pieces of string on either side exert forces with tiny, but nonzero upward components.  If you half the length we are considering to 0.5 mm, then the upward component of the forces is smaller, but so is the weight!  Half that again to 0.25 mm, and the same happens.  By the time you're actually considering about the part of the string that is in the **exact** middle of the wire, as you say the tension forces are perfectly horizontal, but that piece of the wire has zero mass & weight, so there's no need for any vertical force to support it.

In reality, that's a little silly, because wires are not ideal objects.  But the same principle applies.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  I have a followup question though, if you don't mind.  When I draw a FBD for this system with a rope length of L, I get $gm = f \sin(\theta)$, where $m$ is the mass of the rope section, $f$ is the right tension force, and $\theta$ is the angle between the tangent of the rope and the horizontal at the rightmost part of the rope section.  But $m$ decreases linearly with $L$, and $\sin(\theta)$ decreases even faster than that (because catenary curve).  So shouldn't $f$ go to infinity?

Comment: (and isn't this bad, because it implies infinite tension force on the middle part of the rope, which would break the rope?)

Comment: @GMB: Have you checked Wikipedia? It's fairly easy to see that the horizontal part of the tension factor cannot change as the two horizontal forces on either end of the chain are mirror-symmetric and gravity is vertical.